# Searching for a heading in MS Word

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, ms-word, pywin32

I am searching through a word document for headings and autonumbering and assigning them to tuples.

```
(Heading Style, 1.1, text)
```

Currently I am using a for loop to pass every Paragraph object in the document and searching it.

```
   for x in xrange(1, doc.Paragraphs.Count+1):#for loop to print through paragraphs
    oText = doc.Paragraphs(x)
    if not oText.Range.Tables.Count >0 :
        results = re.match('(?P<number>(([1-3]*[A-D]*[0-9]*)(.[1-3]*[0-9])+))', oText.Range.Text)
        stylematch = re.match('Heading (?P<i>\d)', oText.Style.NameLocal)
        if results!= None and oText.Style != None and stylematch != None:
            doccat.append((oText.Style.NameLocal, oText.Range.Text[:len(results.group('number'))],oText.Range.Text[len(results.group('number')):]))
            style = oText.Style.NameLocal
```

Is there a more efficient way to just search for headings rather than calling and examining every Paragraph object in the Word document?

**EDIT:**

I should also mention I am using this:

```
doc.ConvertNumbersToText()
```

to convert the autonumbering into something searchable in the Paragraph text.

**SECOND EDIT:**

I am not looking for the Table Of Contents, although I would like to be able to as an option.  I'm merely looking for Heading 1,2,3,4,5,6...etc.

Comment: It is worse than this, in that you should also look for styles which are based on heading styles.  Also, do you care about outline level?

Answer (score 0):

If you record a macro in Word, and use Goto (Ctrl-G), select Headings in the dialog, you will obtain a statement like:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:=""
```

In the GoTo dialog, you can also select Fields, AUTONUM, if this is the type of auto-numbering you are referring to.

Alternatively, record a macro using Advanced Find, click the Format button and Style.. to obtain:

```
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
```

this allows you to specify the particular Heading style.

A third option would be to create a **Table Of Contents** - which is based on the Heading-styles - grab its text, then `Undo` the TOC. (I haven't attempted this, but feel sure it would work. It depends, of course, on your specific intentions.)

Comment: I'm planning on inputting this data in Access later, so I'm merely parsing the document into chunks.

Comment: Hello @Doof12. The TOC was just a suggestion if you needed to get the text from the headings, deleting the TOC afterwards. However, if you want to parse the documents into chunks then I would look into the `Outline View` (from the View tab). Here you can collapse the inner content of different heading levels, copy and paste them, display only certain headings, etc..